# EF Relationship entre 3 Tabelas

Tags: entity-framework

Estou aprendendo Entity Framework usando Code First e encontrei uma dificuldade com relacionamentos.

Tenho três tabelas no sistema que eu estou fazendo:

- Fluxo (Chave = ID_FLUXO);
- Passo (Chave = ID_PASSO);
- Acao (Chave = ID_ACAO);

Preciso de duas tabelas: uma que relacione o Fluxo (FLUXO_X_PASSO) e uma que associe as três... (FLUXO_X_PASSO_X_ACAO).

Consegui fazer a primeira parte usando Fluent API como no código abaixo:

```
   HasMany(w => w.Steps)
    .WithMany(w => w.Workflows)
    .Map(m => 
        { 
          m.MapLeftKey("ID_FLUXO"); 
          m.MapRightKey("ID_PASSO"); 
          m.ToTable("TB_FLUXO_X_PASSO"); 
        });
```

Porém, não sei como fazer no segundo caso. Tipo, precisaria de algo como:

```
   HasMany(w => w.Steps)
    .WithMany(w => w.Workflows)
    .Map(m => 
        { 
          m.MapLeftKey("ID_FLUXO"); 
          m.MapRightKey("ID_PASSO"); 
          ** m.Map???("ID_ACAO"); **
          m.ToTable("TB_FLUXO_X_PASSO_X_ACAO"); 
        });
```

Acabei criando o banco na mão e tentei fazer engenharia reversa com o PowerTools, mas ele também não conseguiu fazer a segunda parte.

Alguém vê uma saída para essa questão ou é melhor não usar o EF neste caso específico?

Comment: Depende do que vc deseja fazer, porque isso não  é viável do jeito que fez e a ferramenta gera em cima de padrões...

Comment: Desculpe, Potter, mas qual o erro que cometi? Como disse, estou aprendendo e qualquer orientação é muito válida!

Comment: Eu precisa mesmo entender porque 3 chaves, um estudo mais detalhado a sua pergunta é boa mas, fica meio inviável fazer assim!

Comment: vai depender do que você deseja implementar, porque, ali é muitos para muitos é são dois campos chaves somente!

Comment: Explico: é o fluxo do meu sistema. Existem vários fluxos e estes fluxos possuem passos. Cada passo desse fluxo possui diversas ações (atividades) que levarão para passos diferentes dependendo de qual ação foi executada. Por isso a chave tríplice. Ajuda? Rsrs

Comment: Sim @Rubens a resposta do Cigano seria a solução para o seu sistema!!!

Comment: eu fiz um exemplo passando desde a base até o entity com fluent.

Comment: @Rubens Poderia por favor aceitar a resposta correta? Isso se faz clicando no ícone em formato de 'V' abaixo do contador de votos de cada resposta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom vou propor a esse modelo então:

***Base de dados - Layout***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Classes Modelos e Fluent Mapeamento***

```cs
public partial class Acao
{
    public Acao()
    {
        this.FluxoPassoAcaos = new List<FluxoPassoAcao>();
    }

    public int ID_ACAO { get; set; }
    public string DESCRICAO { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FluxoPassoAcao> FluxoPassoAcaos { get; set; }
}

public class AcaoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Acao>
{
    public AcaoMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID_ACAO);
        this.Property(t => t.DESCRICAO).HasMaxLength(50);
        this.ToTable("Acao");
        this.Property(t => t.ID_ACAO).HasColumnName("ID_ACAO");
        this.Property(t => t.DESCRICAO).HasColumnName("DESCRICAO");
    }
}
```

---

```cs
public partial class Fluxo
{
    public Fluxo()
    {
        this.FluxoPassoAcaos = new List<FluxoPassoAcao>();
    }

    public int ID_FLUXO { get; set; }
    public string DESCRICAO { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FluxoPassoAcao> FluxoPassoAcaos { get; set; }
}
public class FluxoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Fluxo>
{
    public FluxoMap()
    {       
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID_FLUXO);
        this.Property(t => t.DESCRICAO).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
        this.ToTable("Fluxo");
        this.Property(t => t.ID_FLUXO).HasColumnName("ID_FLUXO");
        this.Property(t => t.DESCRICAO).HasColumnName("DESCRICAO");
    }
}
```

---

```cs
public partial class Passo
{
    public Passo()
    {
        this.FluxoPassoAcaos = new List<FluxoPassoAcao>();
    }
    public int ID_PASSO { get; set; }
    public string DESCRICAO { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FluxoPassoAcao> FluxoPassoAcaos { get; set; }
}
public class PassoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Passo>
{
    public PassoMap()
    {       
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID_PASSO);
        this.Property(t => t.DESCRICAO).HasMaxLength(50);
        this.ToTable("Passo");
        this.Property(t => t.ID_PASSO).HasColumnName("ID_PASSO");
        this.Property(t => t.DESCRICAO).HasColumnName("DESCRICAO");
    }
}
```

---

```cs
public partial class FluxoPassoAcao
{
    public int ID_FLUXO { get; set; }
    public int ID_PASSO { get; set; }
    public int ID_ACAO { get; set; }
    public virtual Acao Acao { get; set; }
    public virtual Fluxo Fluxo { get; set; }
    public virtual Passo Passo { get; set; }
}
public class FluxoPassoAcaoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoPassoAcao>
{
    public FluxoPassoAcaoMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.ID_FLUXO, t.ID_PASSO, t.ID_ACAO });        
        this.Property(t => t.ID_FLUXO).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        this.Property(t => t.ID_PASSO).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        this.Property(t => t.ID_ACAO).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        this.ToTable("FluxoPassoAcao");
        this.Property(t => t.ID_FLUXO).HasColumnName("ID_FLUXO");
        this.Property(t => t.ID_PASSO).HasColumnName("ID_PASSO");
        this.Property(t => t.ID_ACAO).HasColumnName("ID_ACAO");

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Acao)
            .WithMany(t => t.FluxoPassoAcaos)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ID_ACAO);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Fluxo)
            .WithMany(t => t.FluxoPassoAcaos)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ID_FLUXO);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Passo)
            .WithMany(t => t.FluxoPassoAcaos)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ID_PASSO);
    }
}
```

---

***Classe Generics***

```cs
public partial class GenericsContext : DbContext
{
    public GenericsContext()
        : base("Name=GenericsContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Acao> Acao { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Fluxo> Fluxo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FluxoPassoAcao> FluxoPassoAcao { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Passo> Passos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AcaoMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FluxoMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FluxoPassoAcaoMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PassoMap());        
    }
}
```

---

***Inserir***

```cs
using (GenericsContext db = new GenericsContext())
{
    Passo passo = new Passo();
    passo.DESCRICAO = "Passo";
    db.Passo.Add(passo);
    db.SaveChanges();


    Fluxo fluxo = new Fluxo();
    fluxo.DESCRICAO = "Fluxo";
    db.Fluxo.Add(fluxo);
    db.SaveChanges();


    Acao acao = new Acao();
    acao.DESCRICAO = "Acao";
    db.Acao.Add(acao);
    db.SaveChanges();


    FluxoPassoAcao fluxopassoacao = new FluxoPassoAcao();
    fluxopassoacao.Acao = acao;
    fluxopassoacao.Fluxo = fluxo;
    fluxopassoacao.Passo = passo;
    db.FluxoPassoAcao.Add(fluxopassoacao);
    db.SaveChanges();

}
```

---

***Pesquisar pelo FluxoPassoAcao***

```cs
FluxoPassoAcao findFPA = db.FluxoPassoAcao.Where(x =>x.ID_PASSO == 2 && x.ID_ACAO == 2 && x.ID_FLUXO == 2).FirstOrDefault();
```

*Perceba que funciona, mas, ai vai depender mesmo se é isso que precisa!*

Comment: Putz valeu cara... Eu estava quase me aproximando dessa solução. Muito obrigado mesmo, Harry e Cigano.

Comment: Valeu Harry e Cigano, funcionou perfeito.

Answer (score 2):

Não conheço sintaxe do Fluent API em que seja possível definir uma associação entre 3 entidades. Acho que fica melhor você mapear o modelo e definir as chaves nele:

```cs
public class FluxoPassoAcao {
    [Key]
    public int FluxoPassoAcaoId { get; set; }
    [Column("FLUXO_ID")]
    public int FluxoId { get; set; }
    [Column("PASSO_ID")]
    public int PassoId { get; set; }
    [Column("ACAO_ID")]
    public int AcaoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Fluxo Fluxo { get; set; }
    public virtual Passo Passo { get; set; }
    public virtual Acao Acao { get; set; }
}
```

Para esta modelagem, os 3 modelos precisam receber o seguinte:

```cs
public class Fluxo {
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<FluxoPassoAcao> FluxosPassosAcoes { get; set; }
}

public class Passo {
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<FluxoPassoAcao> FluxosPassosAcoes { get; set; }
}

public class Acao {
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<FluxoPassoAcao> FluxosPassosAcoes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Valeu Cigano. Vou tentar. 

Mas fiquei curioso como vou trabalhar esses dados depois. 

No caso, como eu buscaria todos os dados de um fluxo, por exemplo?

O Fluxo terá passos e cada passo terá ações. Automaticamente acho que não será possível, certo? Vou ter de preencher o objeto manualmente, é isso? Valeu.

Comment: De maneira alguma. Se os seus modelos foram declarados corretamente, o Entity Framework carrega tudo pra você sozinho. Vou atualizar o exemplo pra você saber como fazer.